# windows hard drive real time replication

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, io, kernel

I am working on a project to replicate windows write requests from one hard disk to another in real time asynchronously.

I am new to kernel mode drivers development under windows, what I have in mind is to monitor IO requests.

I searched a lot but this area is not documented as it should.

I did my search and found 4 leads (but non of them is sure the best option to start with)

- **IRP**

IO request packets used by windows drivers to communicate between them and the OS, but will I be able to monitor the IRP used by the hard disk driver ? and what about the security?

- **Windows filter drivers**

there is a lot of system filter drivers levels from upper to lower, which one should be used? and Will I be able to filter the IOs used by the hard disk driver?

- **IO hooks**

this technique is used by windows antiviruses to hook the IOs and check the files. Is it reliable to use in my situation ?

- **kernel event tracing**

Used by Microsoft Diskmon tool to monitor hard disk activity.

The problem here is that I don't know where to start and what is the best option to start with in terms of performance and security.

Comment: What are your security concerns?  Any other kernel mode code will be able to do anything it likes to you; no user mode code will be able to touch you.

Comment: I mean security concerns regarding other drivers, will I be able to monitor IO requests used by hard disk driver ?

Comment: Called RAID1.  Nobody can *reliably* and competitively program against a [19 dollar solution](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124152).

Comment: @HansPassant yes RAID1, but the difference I need to implement it Async and have more control over the data being replicated.
Also the solution is implementing hardware RAID, I need to implement kind of soft raid solution

Comment: That's a fallacy as well.  You don't know *anything* about the data.  You'll have no idea what the data represents, you don't even know where it is stored in the file system.  So you have no control.  If you want a proper solution instead of just a bunch of random guesses that help nobody then it is *essential* that you describe your "control" intentions.

Comment: @HansPassant I need to replicate the data from a disk (block level) to iscsi target, so that the target will be a mirror of the source. this is not optional with hardware raid since i want to make heat maps on the block level.

Answer (score 1):

you at first must perfect understand [`windows Storage, Volumes, and File System Stacks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/storage-device-stacks--storage-volumes--and-file-system-stacks) and use [`Device Tree`](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=97)

determinate which device you need filter, and as UpperFilter or Lowfilter. you really need replicate disk, or say partition(volume) on disk or file-systems read/write ?

for attach to device you can register self in registry, say for disk filter - under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}` in `UpperFilters` or `LowerFilters`

read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/storage/device-object-example-for-a-scsi-hba) storage stack example
your place is at (4) (LowFilter - you will be filter `IRP_MJ_SCSI` for read/write) or (7) (UpperFilter - you will be filter `IRP_MJ_READ`/`IRP_MJ_WRITE` for read/write)
driver must be or direct `WDM` (register `AddDevice` in Driver) or use `KMDF` (shell framework)

another solution use [`IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549526(v=vs.85).aspx)(`EventCategoryDeviceInterfaceChange`, &[`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545824(v=vs.85).aspx)) for attach disk `FDO` - here you always will be UpperFilter

and the best resource for ask this kind of question, advice - is [osronline](http://www.osronline.com/index.cfm) - NTFSD or NTDEV forum

Comment: Thank you for your references they look really helpful, regarding your question, I need to replicate the whole disk on the block level

Comment: @AhmedKato - so you need - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/storage/storage-filter-drivers . and determinate low or high filter - `A lower-level SFD monitors SRBs and/or IRPs issued by a storage class driver`, A higher-level storage filter driver (SFD) intercepts IRPs from user applications